# Add a cache to json_decode Twitter API

Tags: php, caching, twitter, json

I'm trying to add a cache machanism to json_decode fetching Twitter API. The important part is the one regarding $cache and the if below it.

```
<?php
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }

    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); //return complete base string
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";

    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$oauth_access_token = "XXXXXXXXX";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "XXXXXXX";
$consumer_key = "XXXXXXX";
$consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'count' => 6,   
    'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;


$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?count=6',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$cache = './wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/twitter_json/'.sha1($url).'.json';
        if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 1000){
            // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exist, use it
            $twitter_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
        } else {
            $twitter_data = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
            file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($twitter_data));
        }


    echo "<ul style='color:#6E6E6E'>";
    foreach ($twitter_data as $tweet)
    {
        if (!empty($tweet)) {
            $text = $tweet->text;
            $text_in_tooltip = str_replace('"', '', $text); // replace " to avoid conflicts with title="" opening tags
            $id = $tweet->id;
            $time = strftime('%d %B', strtotime($tweet->created_at));
            $username = $tweet->user->name;
        }
        echo '<li><span title="'; echo $text_in_tooltip; echo '">'; echo $text . "</span><br>
            <a href=\"http://twitter.com/"; echo $username ; echo '/status/'; echo $id ; echo '"><small>'; echo $time; echo '</small></a> - 
            <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='; echo $id; echo '"><small>rispondi</small></a> - 
            <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='; echo $id; echo '"><small>retweet</small></a> - 
            <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='; echo $id; echo '"><small>preferito</small></a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Unfortunately I'm getting these errors:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
 in /wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/homepage_copy.php on line 62
PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(./wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/twitter_json/38f925d2889d7b60d4f18c448a90ab03419721c4.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/homepage_copy.php on line 63
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/homepage_copy.php on line 68" while reading response header from upstream, client: 94.37.252.247, server: multiformeingegno.it, request: "GET /wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/homepage_copy.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "multiformeingegno.it"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to open the twitter url using file_get_contents when you have a cache miss, which is totally unnecessary since you already got the json data via curl

See the ** commented ** line in the code below

```
$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$cache = './wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/twitter_json/'.sha1($url).'.json';
    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 1000){
        // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exist, use it
        $twitter_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    } else {
        // ** decode the json you got from the curl request here **
        $twitter_data = json_decode($json);
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($twitter_data));
    }
```

Comment: Now the tweets appear, but in /twitter_json/ there's no file..
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(./wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/twitter_json/38f925d2889d7b60d4f18c448a90ab03419721c4.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/homepage_copy.php on line 63" while reading response header from upstream, client: 94.37.252.247, server: multiformeingegno.it, request: "GET /wp-content/themes/multiformeingegno/homepage_copy.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"

Comment: And I set correct permissions for the folder (writable by webserver).

Comment: The file path will be relative to the folder that `homepage_copy.php` is in, try `./twitter_json/'.sha1($url).'.json';` as the cache path